# Encontrar palavra INTEIRA em uma string em C

Tags: c

Olá.

Preciso procurar uma palavra em um texto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *word = "dado"; // palavra a ser encontrada
    char *pageContent = "Ola tudo bem, vamos jogar dados"; // texto para procurar

    char* result = strstr(pageContent, word);

    printf("result: %s", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Porém, nesse caso está retornando "dados". O texto contém a palavra "DADOS" mas eu quero encontrar "DADO", apenas. Como faço para encontrar uma palavra inteira, sem que ela seja parte de outra palavra? Obrigado.

Comment: A situação mais geral é a palavra estar entre espaços. Contudo ela pode iniciar na primeira posição ou terminar na última, com o correspondente espaço após ou antes. O outro caso que você precisará considerar é a pontuação. Uma outra coisa é se você vai diferenciar ou não as letras maiúsculas das minúsculas.

Comment: Encontrar ou devolver ? No seu exemplo era suposto a pesquisa falhar pois não existe apenas a palavra "dado" ou retornar só a parte "dado" ?

Comment: se não encontrar a palavra ele retorna NULL, no meu exemplo eu espero que seja retornado NULL, pois a palavra 'dado' não existe só 'dados'

Comment: O problema foi resolvido? Se alguma resposta é adequada você pode aceitá-la, ou se nenhuma resolve você pode postar a sua própria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em C, a função `strstr` em C retorna um ponteiro para a primeira ocorrência da palavra a ser procurada. Ou seja, após a palavra ser encontrada, todos os caracteres após essa substring serão incluídos no resultado.

Por exemplo, se `char *word = "joga";`, será retornado `"jogar dados"`.

Para contornar isso, você pode usar o comprimento da substring `word`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char *word = "dado";
    char *pageContent = "Ola tudo bem, vamos jogar dados";
    char* result = strstr(pageContent, word);

    printf("result: ");
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
        printf("%c", *(result + i));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "Ola tudo bem, vamos jogar dados";
    char search[] = "dado";
    char *ptr = strstr(str, search);

    if (ptr != NULL) /* Substring encontrada */
    {
        printf("'%s' contém'%s'\n", str, search);
    }
    else /* Substring não encontrada */
    {
        printf("'%s' não contém '%s'\n", str, search);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: olá amigo, não funcionou. O problema permanece o mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Uma meneira de fazer é utilizando **strtok()**: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/.
Só deve-se tomar cuidado com o uso desta função pois ela *modifica* a string que ela recebe como argumento.

```
    char word[] = "dado"; // palavra a ser encontrada
    char pageContent[] = "dado ddado dadoo, .dado.?dado! !dados!"; // texto para procurar
    char *pt = NULL, str[100];
    strcpy(str, pageContent);
    pt = strtok(str, ",. !?"); // delimitadores que dividem as palavras
    int found=0;
    while( pt != NULL){
        if(!strcmp(word, pt)){
            printf("Found at position: %d\n", pt - str);
            found++;
        }
        pt = strtok(NULL, ",. !?");
    }   
    printf("We found %d ocurrences of the word: %s\n", found, word);
```

Acredito que usando outras funções e adequando à necessidade, seria mais rápido, mas deste jeito parece mais óbvio.